# Java Point Errors

Tags: java

I am running through a tutorial and getting different results from the video. I keep throwing three errors when trying to run a simple println of a point:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point point1 = new Point(x:1, y:1);
        Point point2 = point1;
        point1.x = 2;
        System.out.println(point2);
    }
}
```

Error:(8, 35) java: ')' expected

Error:(8, 41) java: not a statement

Error:(8, 42) java: ';' expected

Please Advise.

Comment: What are you expecting `x:1`  to do? Where is `x` defined?

Comment: Java does not have named method arguments. Is that really the code shown in your video?

Comment: Recording error codes with line number only makes sense, when the line numbers match the code you show. In this case it was easy to figure out, what the issue was, since the error is so obvious, so after solving the error, we can deduce the correct line numbering. It should be the other way round, so insert a dummy remark if you have to obfuscate company names in copyright remarks or compile the cleaned up SE version of your code.

Comment: I only started Java less than a week ago. Thank you for your patience. For those asking about the video, the code is shown here starting at 40:30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIrMbAQSU34&t=2603s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that is not java. Java does not have named parameters; it never did and no such feature is on the horizon. Thus, `new Point(x: 1, y: 1)` is illegal java. Legal java is `new Point(1, 1)`.